# integrate points into base R plot in respect to second axis

Tags: r, boxplot

With a very simple example, I wish to create a boxplot of distribution X and then add the points of Y with respect to a second vertical axis. can someone offer some advice or assistance?

```
set.seed(123)
A <- rnorm(100, 4, 1)
B <- rnorm(100, 25, 5)

# create our simple boxplot
boxplot(A, ylim=c(0,10))

# then our second axis
axis(4, at = seq(0, 10, by = 1), labels= seq(0, 100, by = 10),las=2)

# want to create vertical poins for each B value
# possibly with some jitter
par(new = TRUE)
points(B, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim=c(0,100), col="green")
```

The desired output should look like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
par(mar=c(4,4,1,4))
boxplot(A)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(rep(1,length(B)), B, col="green", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4, at =seq(0, 100, by = 10))
```

## EDIT:

As you included a picture of your expected result I found another solution using `beeswarm`

```
library(beeswarm)
boxplot(list(A, B), ylim=range(A))
par(new = TRUE)
beeswarm(list(A, B), pwcol=c(rep(0,length(A)),rep(2,length(B))), axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0, 100))
axis(4, at =seq(0, 100, by = 10), las= 2)
```

[image]